# How do I make a discord.py embed?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

The code essentially is supposed to create an embed and for some reason it gives me the error " 'message' is not defined" (the embed will be put into anoter bot)

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random
from discord.ext.commands import Bot



class MyClient(discord.Client):

    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as', self.user)
        channel = self.get_channel(717005397655027805)
        await channel.send("I am now online")

        messageContent = message.Content
        if message.author == self.user:
            return

        @client.event
        async def on_message(message):
            if message.content.startswith('!hello'):
                embedVar = discord.Embed(
                    title="Title", description="Desc", color=0x336EFF
                )
                embedVar.add_field(name="Field1", value="hi", inline=False)
                embedVar.add_field(name="Field2", value="hi2", inline=False)
                client.send_message(message.channel, embed=embedVar)

                PREFIX = ("$")
                bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=PREFIX, description='Hi')



client = MyClient()
client.run('TOKEN')
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You didn't specify what `message.Content` is in on the `on_ready()` function, also you need to create the `on_message()` function outside of the `on_ready()` func, and you didn't specify what the `@client` decorator is, you just specified it at the end of your code.

All in all, your fixed code should look something like this

```py
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN  = "Your token here"
PREFIX = '$'
bot    = commands.Bot(command_prefix=PREFIX)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged on as', bot.user)
    channel = bot.get_channel(717005397655027805)
    await channel.send("I am now online")

@bot.command() # Usage - $hello
async def hello(ctx):
    if ctx.message.author == bot.user: return
    embedVar = discord.Embed(title="Title", description="Desc", color=0x336EFF)
    embedVar.add_field(name="Field1", value="hi", inline=False)
    embedVar.add_field(name="Field2", value="hi2", inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Your code is still a bit faulty. Your `message` is not defined.

Comment: Mate, he is using `Classes and Objects` so I think you need to give the code in OOP type not this.

Comment: he isnt using cogs, so he doesnt need oop

Comment: Hey, I really thank you for your contribution, I would like to let you know that the code did not work and the error code says " 'self' is not defined "

Comment: whoops forgot to change from `self.user` to `bot.user`

Comment: Many many thanks good sir it works now you are awesome.

Comment: ok, if it solves it, please mark this as the solution to your question

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I have now marked it as problem solving reply.

Answer (score 2):

As you use `CLASSES AND OBJECTS` or `OOP` for the bot you need correct syntax too. I can't really help you with than but can use normal way.

### Step 1:

We will import the libraries:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random
```

### Step 2:

We will define the Prefix and Bot's variable.

```
PREFIX = "$"
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=PREFIX, description="Hi")
```

### Step 3:

We will now write the bot's `on_ready()` command according to your code.

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged on as', self.user)
    channel = bot.get_channel(717005397655027805)
    await channel.send("I am now online")
```

The statement `bot.get_channel()` is being used to get the channel to send the message.

### Step 4:

We will now write bot's `on_message` function according to your code.

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!hello'):
        embedVar = discord.Embed(
        title="Title", description="Desc", color=0x336EFF
                )
        embedVar.add_field(name="Field1", value="hi", inline=False)
        embedVar.add_field(name="Field2", value="hi2", inline=False)
        await message.channel.send(embed=embedVar)
```

### Step 5:

We will now create a statement to start up your bot.

```
bot.run("TOKEN")
```

Add this command at the bottom of the script.

---

### The whole code compiled will be:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random

PREFIX = "$"
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=PREFIX, description="Hi")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged on as', self.user)
    channel = bot.get_channel(717005397655027805)
    await channel.send("I am now online")

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!hello'):
        embedVar = discord.Embed(
        title="Title", description="Desc", color=0x336EFF
                )
        embedVar.add_field(name="Field1", value="hi", inline=False)
        embedVar.add_field(name="Field2", value="hi2", inline=False)
        await message.channel.send(embed=embedVar)
```

---

This would solve your problem. If you still get any problem, please ask me in the comments. :)

Thank You! :D

Comment: Hey, I really appriciate your work to help me but it still says that 'message' is not defined.

Comment: @Ethan Sorry for that. I saw something wrong. I have now changed the code accordingly. You can follow the steps and see how to write it.

Comment: @Ethan If I was able to help, please accept the answer. :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this (based of Bhavyadeep's code):

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random

PREFIX = "$"
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=PREFIX, description="Hi")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged on as', bot.user)
    # channel = bot.get_channel(717005397655027805)
    # await channel.send("I am now online")

@bot.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    if ctx.content.startswith('!hello'):
        embedVar = discord.Embed(
        title="Title", description="Desc", color=0x336EFF
                )
        embedVar.add_field(name="Field1", value="hi", inline=False)
        embedVar.add_field(name="Field2", value="hi2", inline=False)
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=embedVar)

bot.run("TOKEN")
```

I've simply replaced "message" with "ctx". If this still doesn't work, then try replacing `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=PREFIX, description="Hi")` with `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=PREFIX, description="Hi", pass_context=True)`.
It also appears your indentation in the class MyClient is wrong, so fix that first. Make sure that `async def on_message(`... is in the class scope.

If all fails, try and move the code to the global scope (delete the class).